# Run application with parameters from PowerShell

Tags: windows-10, powershell

On a Win10 System I would like to execute the following command (taken from a working shortcut-file):

```
"C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" U=<username> S=serverName
```

in CMD the following command opens the application without any problems:

```
"C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" "U=<username>" "S=serverName"
```

In PowerShell however I tried various combinations (e.g. including using `Start-Process`, `cmd /c` which always worked for me so far) but they all fail. It's probable something simple, but I can't get it to work. What would be the correct notation?

Comment: I usually just type the cmd command, but ensure that I start with `.\ `. So I'd try: `".\C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" "U=<username>" "S=serverName"`

Comment: @LPChip using `cmd /c ".\C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" "U=<username>" "S=serverName"` It tells me it cant find the file

Comment: yeah, I did not say using cmd /c... In Powershell, you can start programs by just typing .\program

Comment: I tried that as well. As single string it's like using echo (just an output of the string without the quotation marks) and as three separate strings I get an error message "unknown token" (loosely translated from German). But Start-Process works, so you don't need to bother, unless you are interested.

Comment: Nah. Its okay. I just wanted to ensure you understood cmd /c will not work, then it would be `.\cmd /c "command and params"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" -ArgumentList "U=<username> S=serverName"
```

Comment: With some improvement: `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Path with spaces\application.exe" -ArgumentList 'U=<username>', 'S=serverName', '"eg pathname with spaces as single argument"'`